# How can I remove the values on top of the grouped bars with the bar_plot using axes.bar in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: [Bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mnZ2.png)]

I want to remove the percentage values on top of each plot, or possibly round them

```
width = 0.2
x = np.arange(len(labels))

fig2,ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, precision_data, width, label='precision',color ='firebrick')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2 , recall_data, width, label='recall',color = 'royalblue')

ax.set_ylabel('Score %')
ax.set_title('precision-recall average classifiers scores')
ax.set_xticks(x, labels)
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1)
ax.bar_label(rects2)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To **remove** the text on top of your bars, simply comment out `ax.bar_label(rects1)` and `ax.bar_label(rects2)`:
- To **round** the labels, you may use the `fmt` argument: `ax.bar_label(labels, fmt='%.2f')`